# Why does <!-- language: lang-none --> not work for me?

Tags: support, markdown, syntax-highlighting

See this question:

[How can I make Doxygen not document my include guard?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56190192/1593077)

I've used three-backticks, newline, then `<!-- language: lang-none -->`. And - C-style comments cause a graying-out of the rest of the text.

Why, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's the HTML-specific formatting. It would work if your code block looked like:

```
<!-- language: language-here  -->

    foo();
```

You use code fences, which means you need to use a different syntax. Specifically:

````
```language-here
foo();
```
````

This is also outlined [in the code fence announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/322000/332043) over on MSE. Not all languages are supported though - [here's a list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/332043) of those that are.

Comment: But, @Zoe, that doesn't work either. Just have a look at the result of your edit.

Comment: Only one of your code blocks attempted to use `language-none`, so I only fixed it on that one. [And it renders fine for me](https://i.imgur.com/nzCzveh.png)

Comment: My bad, I used the language setting on the wrong block.